# Drupal JavaScript settings versus jQuery.data()

Tags: javascript

When I writing JavaScript code for my module, I could use [jQuery.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) or the setting object passed to the Drupal behavior my module add.

Should a module always use the settings object, or could I use `jQuery.data()` in my module?
Is there any case where using `jQuery.data()` is problematic when used in AJAX code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I used `Drupal.settings` as a read-only object for communicating settings and configuration information from PHP to JS.  Runtime state isn't appropriate here.

`jQuery.data()` should only really be used to pull out data attributes that you have set via PHP, and for setting data that is specific to **that element-only**.

Runtime logic and state should be stored in its own closure.  I use a variant of the [Javascript Module Pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html), which I have adapted for Drupal.  Boilerplate looks like:

```
var FOO = (function(me, $, Drupal, undefined) {
    me.name = "FOO";

    // local properties

    var foo = null;
    var bar = null;

    // local functions

    function somethingAwesome () {
        console.log(me.name + '.' + arguments.callee.name + '()');
    }

    // global properties

    me.baz = null;

    // global functions

    me.somethingAwesomer () = function somethingAwesomer {
        console.log(me.name + '.' + arguments.callee.name + '()');
    };

    // Drupal

    function init (context, settings) {
        if (settings.foo) {
            console.log(me.name + '.' + arguments.callee.name + '()', $.fn.jquery);

            // do stuff
        }

        Drupal.behaviors[me.name] = undefined;
    };

    Drupal.behaviors[me.name] = {
        attach: init
    };

    return me;
}(FOO || {}, jQuery, Drupal));
```

I don't do a lot of true behaviors, though, hence making my initialization function a oneshot.

Answer (score 1):

They're not used for the same thing...

[`jQuery.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) is used for storing data *specific to a DOM element*.

> Store arbitrary data associated with the specified element and/or return the value that was set.

The `Drupal.settings` object is for storing global settings specific to the enclosing page build. It's essentially used to pass data from PHP to JavaScript, not to pass/store data within a a client-side page view.

> ...Drupal's global storage of JavaScript settings. Per-page settings are required by some modules to function properly.

If you want to store data related to a particular DOM element, against that DOM element, then use the `jQuery.data()` method.

If you want to pass global page settings from PHP to Javascript, use [`drupal_add_js()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) with the 'setting' type (which results in the data being added to `Drupal.settings` in the front end).

You may well find yourself in the position where you're looping through items in `Drupal.settings` in order to save the same data against the appropriate DOM element - that's perfectly normal (in my experience anyway, a more worldly JS ninja might be able to correct me there though).

Comment: I could output `<div data-role="page" data-last-value="43">[...]</div>` from a theme function defined in my module, and those "data-" attributes would be returned from `jQuery.data()` to JavaScript code. What probably confuses me is the fact that the setting object is passed as parameter for a Drupal behavior; that took me to understand that the setting object could change basing on the element to which the behavior is applied.

Comment: I take a little issue with the last paragraph.  `Drupal.settings` should really just be settings.  If your elements needs data, render it out with data attribute.

Comment: @MPD It's standard practice - store a bunch of selectors and settings inside `Drupal.settings`, then apply those to the relevant elements using `jQuery.data()` in `Drupal.behaviors`. A lot of modules use that method, and probably some elements of core as well

Comment: @kiam yeah I never understood why you get a full copy if the settings object per behavior - presumably it's a js closure thing

Comment: @Clive  I think that is a leftover from D6.  Since D7 ships with JQuery 1.4.4, data attributes are automagically available via .data().

Comment: @MPD True of course, but it does depend somewhat. I know everyone _should_ be using an HTML5 `DOCTYPE` these days, but there are still many legacy XHTML sites which can't take advantage of those attributes while still passing validation. For a generic Drupal module it's best to cater for both, hence the strangled route to backwards-compatibility. I do take your point though